# moment.js diff date formatting

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm using moment.js and want to calculate the difference between two timestamp,format them afterwards and display them in a div.

```
var diffTime = moment(1390310146.791877).diff( 1390309386.271075);
```

This gives me 760 seconds, but I want to format it like this:

(days, hrs,  mins,  secs) and only show days, hours and seconds if they are higher than 0.

How do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 32):

moment.duration should be used

```
   let startTime = moment('09:45:20', 'h:mm:ss A').format("HH:mm:ss");
   let endTime = moment('10:30:35', 'h:mm:ss A').format("HH:mm:ss")
   var todayDate = moment(new Date()).format("MM-DD-YYYY"); //Can change, based on the requirement
   var startDate = new Date(`${todayDate} ${startTime}`);
   var endDate = new Date(`${todayDate} ${endTime}`);
   var diffTime = moment(endDate).diff(startDate);

   var duration = moment.duration(diffTime);
   var years = duration.years(),
    days = duration.days(),
    months = duration.months(),
    hrs = duration.hours(),
    mins = duration.minutes(),
    secs = duration.seconds();

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = years + ' years ' + months + 'months ' + days + ' days ' + hrs + ' hrs ' + mins + ' mins ' + secs + ' sec';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5cedac2/)

Comment: In order for this to work properly you would also need months.    `months = duration.months()`

Comment: ^ Good point. Besides months, you also need `weeks = duration.weeks()`
Otherwise, if you add up the time breakdown, it won't match the diff total.

Comment: I added months. Weeks, however, are not necessary because that time is accounted for in days.

Comment: dayjs is the recommended library to replace moment, but it works exactly the same as described in this answer. https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/https-medium-com-sabesan96-why-you-should-choose-day-js-instead-of-moment-js-9cf7bb274bbd

Answer (score 21):

try this

```
var diffTime = moment(moment(1390310146.791877).diff( 1390309386.271075)).format('H m s');
```

it will output "5 30 0"

**Edit**

here is the simple way to get the difference. for this both the time should be in the same timezone.

```
var a = moment(1390310146.791877);
var b = moment(1390309386.271075);
a.diff(b)//To get the difference in milliseconds
a.diff(b,'seconds')//To get the difference in seconds
a.diff(b,'minutes')//To get the difference in minutes 
a.zone()//Get the timezone offset in minutes
```

hope this helps.

Comment: It should return around 12 mins and 40 secs

Comment: it depends on the local browser timezone.

Comment: I'm not sure yet how to get the correct timedifference between the two timestamps?

Comment: How do I cope with the browser timezone?

Comment: a.diff(b) returns 760 which is actually the seconds. So a.diff(b,'seconds') and a.diff(b,'minutes') both return 0

Comment: I could not make this to work. I think this solution does not address daylight savings. E.g.: if the diff is small (usually) then we have a date in 1970 January no DST and if you do it in the summer (DST). So it messes up the 'zones'.