# calculate date-time difference in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am getting this as follow.

```
var startDateTime = '2017-08-29T11:00:51+05:30';
var endDateTime = '2018-09-30T12:01:52+05:30';
```

and I want to calculate date & time difference in NodeJS & momentJS .. etc libraries I am looking.

```
var startDateTime = '2017-08-29T11:00:51+05:30';
var endDateTime = '2018-09-30T12:01:52+05:30';
```

result date-time difference should be 1year-1month-1day-1hr-1min-1sec
result date-time difference should be 1year-1month-1day-1hr-1min-1sec

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get hours difference between two dates in Moment Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.js diff date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307897/moment-js-diff-date-formatting)