# How to check if there has been a time change between to UNIX timestamps

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, dst

So in my local time zone (Eastern Standard Time), 1 hour has been added to local time, meaning at 02:00 AM on march 14th we jumped to 03:00 AM.

My goal here is to find, by comparing two UNIX timestamps, with the same HH:MM:s, one before the time change as occurred and the other after, that between those two there has been a time change, and if so what it is.

I am using `moment.js`, but calculating the diff between those 2 dates with the same daytime will give 0 hour diff.

```
    //Sat Mar 13 2021 16:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
    const before = moment(1615669200000);

    //Sun Mar 14 2021 16:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
    const after = moment(1615752000000)

    const diff = before.diff(after, 'hours')

    // console.log(diff) will print 0, not 1
```

Comment: In the US the time jump happens at 02:00 AM, not 12:00 AM, although I don't think that matters for this question.

Comment: Are you using **timestamps** or other formats? Please share more details, like the code you are using (the given one does not use timestamps)

Comment: Does the [isDST()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/) method solve the problem? Just check if it's the same for both moments.

Comment: `moment.diff(moment).duration()` is what you are looking for. maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307897/moment-js-diff-date-formatting) can help you

Comment: On your code, you are not setting the time values, which will default to `0:0:0` i think. so idealy, it should be 24hours itself.

Comment: @AdarshMohan He's expecting it to be 23 hours because there's a missing hour when DST changes. But moment.js automatically adjusts for that.

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes I am comparing two UNIX timestamp. This code was only so you could see the actual dates being used.

Comment: If you're comparing two timestamps, just check if the difference is a multiple of 86400.

Comment: @Barmar - That would work if the timestamps were representing an *exact* day between them.  Even a millisecond would throw that off.  Also, some time zones switch DST right at midnight, so snapping each timestamp to local midnight wouldn't necessarily work.

Comment: @Philx94 - The example code doesn't represent what you are asking about.  Please edit your question to show us the *actual* code you are asking about, using Unix timestamps if that is what you are needing.  Also note that your question says you have two timestamps but it doesn't really tell us which time zone you are asking about.  Do you mean the user's local time zone? Or something else?

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I have edited my question. Sorry if it was missing some clarity.

Comment: Please share more details - timestamps themselves do not contain a timezone

Comment: @NicoHaase momentjs will convert the timestamp to the user local timezone. I have written what the timezone is.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint you are right I had to multiply by `1000` but this doesn't solve my issue for now

Comment: @Barmar isDST() is the solution I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: `isDST` only tells you if a moment is in DST, not if there is a transition between two moments.

Comment: Well, if I run `isDST` on `before`, and `after` I can compare and see that they aren't both `True` or `False`, thus there has been a change

Comment: They could both be true or both be false and still have a transition between them - even in the same calendar year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need Moment for this (and due to its [current status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), you should consider not using it.)

To know if there is a transition in local time between two timestamps, you will need to search between those timestamps to compare their local offsets from UTC.

```js
function localTimeZoneHasTransitionBetween(t1, t2) {

  if (typeof(t1) !== 'number' || typeof(t2) !== 'number')
    throw "Timestamps must be numbers.";

  if (t1 > t2)
    throw "Timestamps must be in sequence.";

  // Get the local offset of the first timestamp.
  const o = new Date(t1).getTimezoneOffset();

  // Check if it's different from the second timestamp.
  if (new Date(t2).getTimezoneOffset() !== o) {
    // It's different, so there was obviously a transition.
    return true;
  }
  
  // Search linearly between the two timestamps.
  let t = t1;
  while (t < t2)
  {
    if (new Date(t).getTimezoneOffset() !== o) {
      // The timestamps have different local offsets,
      // thus a transition occured somewhere between them.
      return true;
    }
    
    // Advance a day.  Transitions are not likely to occur at smaller intervals.
    t += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }

  // The offsets were always the same, so there was
  // no transition between them.
  return false;
}

// Example usage
console.log(localTimeZoneHasTransitionBetween(1615669200000, 1615752000000));
```

The above performs a linear search.  One could improve its performance by using a binary search.

Also, if you just need to know if the two timestamps have different offsets, you can just call `new Date(timestamp).getTimezoneOffset()` on each one and compare them.  Of course, that won't tell you what's *between* them.